# How to make tcl background proc wait on a file?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to write a proc that waits in the background on a file and launches a command and keeps on getting stuck while waiting
My code:

```
proc stuck_on_kuku {} {  
      while {![file exists kuku]} {   
          after 3000    
      }  
   echo done sleeping ; # here my command should appear
}
```

Now, when I call this proc in background mode, it jams my shell until done. The shell is recording key strokes, but will only consider them after the ***kuku*** file is created
`> after idle stuck_on_kuku`
Also tried to create an uplevel version of the proc, but still gets the same behavior.
Isn't there a way to wait for a file creation without jamming the tcl shell?
My goal is to have 2-3 of these background runs in parallel, each waiting on something else and launching something else.

Oh, and - worth a mention - I have no access to the *Threads* package on this env, so must make do with vanilla tcl 8.6

Comment: Use the second argument to after to emulate threading. In other languages this is called green threads. In Javascript and Tcl it's called the event loop

Answer (score 3):

The `after` command has a blocking and non-blocking mode. You're using it in a blocking way. Simply use it's non-blocking mode:

```
proc stuck_on_kuku {} {
    if {[file exists kuku]} {
        echo done sleeping ; # here your command should appear
    } else {
        after 3000 stuck_on_kuku; # simulated "threading" without threads
    }
}
```

Note that with this set-up you can check the condition much more often and not consume much CPU time. Try `after 100` to check 10 times per second and use almost 0% CPU time.

Comment: Loved the "save CPU power" part! Trying it now

Comment: the *after* command seems to be causing a problem when waiting - there must be some residual cost to the command that makes it take a lot longer than the 3 seconds I give it and the longer it waits, the less likely it is to actually do something. when waiting for an hour (which is short for my runs), the proc never reaches the commands in the positive *if* branch

Comment: I almost never use the blocking form of `after`; there's almost always something else that the program could be usefully doing at the same time. Fortunately, with coroutines (Tcl 8.6 onwards) you can write code that looks very much like the blocking form without being actually blocking.

Comment: @DonalFellows Years of writing programs in Tcl taught me a lot and primed me when I needed to start getting serious with Javascript. I still base a lot of my understanding of asynchronous flow on what I used to do in Tcl

Comment: If you give after 3000 then 3 seconds is merely the `minimum` amount of time it sleeps, not the exact amount. When your script execute depends on how many other events (network, disk I/O etc.) tcl is processing since all this happens in only **one** thread and a single thread cannot execute two things in parallel. If you have an infinite loop such as a `while` in your program the `after` never gets called because again - single threaded - which means that while you execute other code tcl cannot do other things

Comment: If you've done a bit of javascript programming this thread blocking behavior would feel familiar. But tcl has one weapon that most other languages don't have. If you have an infinite loop but also have some event handlers such as `after`s or `fileevent`s then you can call `update` in the infinite loop to give tcl some CPU time to process your `after`

Comment: It seems that the tcl shell I'm using doesn't have the `after ms script` behavior supported in it. checked it in a plain shell and your solution seems valid, but it doesn't help me because I can't use it :-/